# java.io.EOFException and connection.getInputStream()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

how can i fix this probleme i can't get my InputStream 
`InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();`

Function:

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User_Agent", "");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("REQUEST Result", "IOException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("REQUEST Result", "result = " + result);
    return result;
}
```

logcat:

```
05-04 18:18:31.190 5027-5093/? W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readHeaders(HttpEngine.java:621)
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:574)
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
05-04 18:18:31.194 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
05-04 18:18:31.198 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sabrine123.carhapaty.Fragments.AddCarFragment.request(AddCarFragment.java:206)
05-04 18:18:31.198 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sabrine123.carhapaty.Fragments.AddCarFragment$AddAnnonce.doInBackground(AddCarFragment.java:154)
05-04 18:18:31.198 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sabrine123.carhapaty.Fragments.AddCarFragment$AddAnnonce.doInBackground(AddCarFragment.java:122)
05-04 18:18:31.198 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-04 18:18:31.202 5027-5093/? E/REQUEST Result: IOException = null
05-04 18:18:31.206 5027-5093/? D/REQUEST Result: result = 
05-04 18:18:31.206 5027-5027/? I/System.out: erreur = End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) check for null prior to reading a line.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the HttpURLConnection is null before you try to get an InputStream from it.

When getting an input stream from an HttpURLConnection:

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

I don't think it's strictly necessary for you to do `connection.connect()` after you've already done `url.openConnection()`;

I also notice that you're posting content. From the Android Developer [page on HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> For best performance, you should call either setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) when the body length is known in advance, or setChunkedStreamingMode(int) when it is not. Otherwise HttpURLConnection will be forced to buffer the complete request body in memory before it is transmitted, wasting (and possibly exhausting) heap and increasing latency.

That page might address any additional problems you have utilising the class.